# From nested substring i want to store inner substring output

Tags: sql-server-2008

Suppose i have following commands

```
 Declare @input as varchar(500)

  set @input = 'abce,dfg'

  select substring(substring(@input,1,charindex(',',@input)+1),1,2)
```

How can i save result of inner substring in a new variable?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "save result"?  Save where? In the database? In a new variable?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed something, you can do either...

```
declare @innersub varchar(500)
set @innersub = substring(@input,1,charindex(',',@input)+1)
```

Or...

```
declare @innersub varchar(500)
select @innersub = substring(@input,1,charindex(',',@input)+1)
```

Then you can use the `@innersub`...

```
select substring(@innersub,1,2)
```

**UPDATE** (due to more information from OP in comments)

It is *not possible* to both set a variable **and** return values from a single SELECT statement.

The following will always fail...

```
select field1, @var=field2 from table
```

**EDIT**

Have you looked at using a user-defined-function that returns a table?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetSubString ( @input varchar(500) )
RETURNS @result TABLE ( sub1 varchar(500), sub2 varchar(500) )
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @result (sub1, sub2)
    SELECT substring(substring(@input,1,charindex(',',@input)+1),1,2),
        substring(@input,1,charindex(',',@input)+1)
    RETURN
END
```

And then you can call that as...

```
declare @input varchar(500)
set @input = 'abce,dfg'
select sub1, sub2 from dbo.GetSubString(@input)
```

Comment: I want inner substring's result.

Comment: @Harsh, in that case you need to be more specific, because my answer above is doing what your current question is asking for

Comment: Hey i can not write two different select statement..
so is there any other method??

Comment: @Harch, in that case you're completely out of luck, it is not possible to set a variable and return a result from the same SELECT statement

Comment: @Harsh, have you thought of looking at using a user-defined-function that returns a table?

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @input as varchar(500),
 @cInnerStr varchar(500)
  set @input = 'abce,dfg'
 Set @cInnerStr = substring(@input,1,charindex(',',@input)+1)
 select @cInnerStr
```